# Replace "NA" with another cell from same row with R

Tags: r, replace, na

This topic has already been developed here but I am still struggling with it.

I have the following sample:

```
shipType   SHIP_TYPE_VF
UNDEFINED           <NA>
CARGO           <NA>
FISHING Passenger Ship
FISHING           <NA>
UNKNOWN           <NA>

 structure(list(shipType = structure(c(3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 4L), .Label =
 c("CARGO",  "FISHING", "UNDEFINED", "UNKNOWN"), class = "factor"),
 SHIP_TYPE_VF = structure(c(NA,  NA, 1L, NA, NA), .Label = "Passenger
 Ship", class = "factor")), .Names = c("shipType",  "SHIP_TYPE_VF"),
 row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")
```

I am would like to replace the NA in `df$SHIP_TYPE_VF` with the value from `df$shipType`.

When I use the following command:

```
 test$SHIP_TYPE_VF[is.na(test$SHIP_TYPE_VF)] <-
 as.character(test$shipType[is.na(test$SHIP_TYPE_VF)])
```

I have this:

> > Warning message: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, is.na(test$SHIP_TYPE_VF),
> >     value = c(NA,  :   invalid factor level, NA generated

I tried several other options. I understood that the 2 columns should be factors, but even with factors it does not work.

Help is welcome!

Answer (score 2):

The columns are `factor` class, we can convert it to `character` class and it should work fine.  The error occurred because the levels in the other 'shipType' are not present in the 'SHIP_TYPE'.

```
test[] <- lapply(test, as.character)
i1 <- is.na(test$SHIP_TYPE_VF)
test$SHIP_TYPE_VF[i1] <- test$shipType[i1]
```

Or instead of converting to `character` class, we change the `levels` of the `SHIP_TYPE_VF` to include the elements in 'shipType`

```
 levels(test$SHIP_TYPE_VF) <- c(levels(test$SHIP_TYPE_VF), 
                           levels(test$shipType))
 test$SHIP_TYPE_VF[i1] <- test$shipType[i1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the `ifelse()` function

```
df$SHIP_TYPE_VF<- ifelse(is.na(df$SHIP_TYPE_VF), as.character(df$shipType), as.character(df$SHIP_TYPE_VF))
```